# Is there an easy way to script a comparison of a web page over time?

Tags: python, html, bash, compare, diff

I have a website that I want to monitor for changes, specifically in one DIV in the HTML. I was using http://www.followthatpage.com/ to monitor a webpage for changes, but I ran into two issues:

1. It checks the whole site, not just one DIV
2. It only checks the site once per hour

Ideally, I would like to write a bash or python script that does a diff of two files every 15 minutes, and emails any changes. I was thinking I might be able to use the `diff` command after downloading two files, and set it up for a cron to email if there are changes, but I still don't know how to filter only to a specific DIV.

Is there an easier way then figuring out how to do this myself (an existing script)? If not, what would be the best method to do this?

Comment: download it (`urllib`), parse it (`BeautifulSoup`), compare it (roll your own)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the div you want is specific to the site, you will probably have to setup a simple check.

This consists of

- Downloading the HTML - `urllib.urlopen(URL)` or `requests.get(URL)`.
- Extracting just the right section (BeautifulSoup, roll your own)
- Performing your comparison (straight comparison or difflib).

Figuring out what and how to extract the data is going to take you the longest time. I recommend using Developer Tools in Chrome/Firefox.

Let's say we want to know when the counter updates on digitalocean.com. The div for the counter looks like this:

```
<div class='inner'>
<span class='count'>5</span>
<span class='count'>8</span>
<span class='count'>2</span>
<span class='count_delimiter'>,</span>
<span class='count'>4</span>
<span class='count'>1</span>
<span class='count'>7</span>
</div>
```

Sadly, there's no id, which would be really easy to pull out using BeautifulSoup4. (e.g. `soup.find(id="counter")`.

Instead, I would elect to pull out all the inner elements that have class "count".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

resp = requests.get('https://www.digitalocean.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text)
digits = [tag.getText() for tag in soup.find_all(class_="count")]
count = int(''.join(digits))
```

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) has excellent [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for parsing out HTML documents without having to bang your head (depending on how well laid out the site you're scraping is).

Comment: I tried this method, but I can't seem to use urllib2 to open the url I want. I can get www.google.com, but if I use my url it doesn't work.

Comment: Does your URL require authentication? If you provide the URL I can try to help.

Comment: It does not. I started using the requests package instead of urllib2, and I was able to get it. Thanks!

Comment: Oh awesome. requests is A+, and definitely preferred. I never know how often I should point people to third party libraries vs. stdlib.

Comment: If I'm doing something at work, I try to stick to stdlib, but this is a personal project, so I'm not opposed to using third party libs

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it if you have access to a linux terminal is to add a cronjob

```
$ crontab -e
```

and place the following line (everyday at 16:00)

```
0   16   *   *   *   diff_web_page.sh
```

where contents of `diff_web_page.sh` are

```
#!/bin/bash

URL="http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash";
TMP_FILE="/tmp/diff_page.txt";
if [[ ! -f $TMP_FILE ]]; then
    # First time that we are running, create the file and exit.
    lynx -dump "$URL" &> $TMP_FILE;
    # lynx -dump "$URL" | pcegrep -M "<div>.*</div>" > $TMP_FILE
else
    # the file exist, grub the new version and compare it
    lynx -dump "$URL" &> $TMP_FILE.new; ## use pcegrep if required.
    diff -Npaur $TMP_FILE $TMP_FILE.new;
    mv $TMP_FILE.new $TMP_FILE;
fi
```

this will email the diff of the webpage every time its executed in the user@host (at the linux box you are running this cron job).

If you want a specific div, you can awk the output with `pcregrep -M` when dumping the web page with lynx

Comment: cool, I eventually created something like this; but I'll add some stuff from yours to make mine better. Thanks!